# In PHP PDO how to get "RETURNING" clause values of PostgreSQL upsert query

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have this upsert query written in postgreSQL

```
$statement = 'INSERT INTO "CharactersUnlockToBuyLevels"
                ("CharacterId", "LevelId", "AmountToBuy", "EagleStatueId", "Location", 
                 "MapCoordinateTop", "MapCoordinateLeft")
              VALUES 
                (:CharacterId, :LevelId, :AmountToBuy, :EagleStatueId, :Location, 
                 :MapCoordinateTop, :MapCoordinateLeft)
              ON CONFLICT
                ("CharacterId")
              DO UPDATE 
                SET 
                  "LevelId" = EXCLUDED."LevelId",
                  "AmountToBuy" = EXCLUDED."AmountToBuy",
                  "EagleStatueId" = EXCLUDED."EagleStatueId",
                  "Location" = EXCLUDED."Location",
                  "MapCoordinateTop" = EXCLUDED."MapCoordinateTop",
                  "MapCoordinateLeft" = EXCLUDED."MapCoordinateLeft"                            
              RETURNING "CharacterUnlockToBuyLevelId"
             ';
```

The query works fine, and if I run it in PgAdmin, I get the "CharacterUnlockToBuyLevelId" back as expected. However if I prepare it and execute it using PHP's PDO then I can't seem to get the RETURNING value back.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($statement);
$returnedId = $stmt->execute(array(
     'CharacterId' => $characterId,
     'LevelId' => $unlockMethod['LevelId'],
     'AmountToBuy' => $unlockMethod['AmountToBuy'],
     'EagleStatueId' => $unlockMethod['EagleStatueId'],
     'Location' => $unlockMethod['Location'],
     'MapCoordinateTop' => $unlockMethod['MapCoordinateTop'],
     'MapCoordinateLeft' => $unlockMethod['MapCoordinateLeft'],
));
```

This just returns true, so `$returnedId` will not actually hold the id but just the value true. How can I get the RETURNING value from the upsert query back with PDO's prepared statements?

Comment: Have you tried `with i as (. . . ) select i.* from i`?

Comment: That could work, but I would like to keep my queries as clean as possible and not build extra's around it just to get a value back that it is already being returned and am looking for a solution in PHP PDO

Comment: . . I note that the query is returning one column but you seem be reading many of them.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, it either does an update of an existing record, or it insert a new record. I just need to know the primary_key "CharacterUnlockToBuyLevelId" of the updated/inserted record so that's what I am returning

Comment: . . Only the columns in the `RETURNING` clause are returned in the result set.

Comment: I know that, but the execute statement doesn't return those values, it returns `true`on success and `false`when it fails. So how do I use prepared statements using PDO but still get my value from the RETURNING clause. 
I think we are misunderstanding eachother :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php:

> public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )

to get returned val, try [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($statement);
$returnedId = $stmt->execute(array(
     'CharacterId' => $characterId,
     'LevelId' => $unlockMethod['LevelId'],
     'AmountToBuy' => $unlockMethod['AmountToBuy'],
     'EagleStatueId' => $unlockMethod['EagleStatueId'],
     'Location' => $unlockMethod['Location'],
     'MapCoordinateTop' => $unlockMethod['MapCoordinateTop'],
     'MapCoordinateLeft' => $unlockMethod['MapCoordinateLeft'],
));
$yourVal=$stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thank you Vao, I was hoping to get it in one call to the database instead of having to fetch it afterwards but I guess that's not possible then.
Since I know I'm only getting one row back with only one value, I used fetchColumn() instead. This gives me the id number straight away and avoids me having to get it out of the array that fetchAll() or fetch() would return

Answer (score 0):

If you’re prepared to extend the `PDOStatement` class, you can simplify the process a little. The trick is to wrap the `fetchAll` inside your extended version of the `execute` method.

Because the `PDOStatement` is generated indirectly, you first need to tell PDO to use your extended version, rather than the standard version:

```
$pdo=new PDO($dsn,$user,$password) or die('oops');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('DBStatement',array($pdo)));
```

… where `DBStatement` will be your extended `PDOStatement`.

You can then extend the class as follows:

```
class DBStatement extends PDOStatement {
    public $pdo;
    protected function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    function executeReturning($data=null) {
        parent::execute($data);
        return $this->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

The first part is required to get your new class to start off the same as the original. The second part executes the statement, and then returns the result.

You can then call it as follows:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO testing(data) VALUES(?) RETURNING id,data';
$pds=$pdo->prepare($sql);
print_r($pds->executeReturning(['this space for rent']));
```